# Urls in pagination

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Can anyone tell me, how Can i create urls in pagination. At this moment i have:

controller:

```
$scope.pagination = function(pages) {
    return new Array(pages);
}
```

list:

```
<span ng-repeat="pagee in pagination(pages) track by $index" ng-if="$index < 10">
   <button ng-if="page+$index < pages+1" ng-class="{ active: isActive(page+$index) }" ng-click='loadProducts(page+$index, pageSize)' class="btn btn-default">{{page+$index}}</button>
</span>
```

And question is how can I create url that, when I Click on button  (4) is creating :
in url: numberPage and sizePage, and when I after enter this link, it will redirect me to this page.

I am working with node.js/angularJS

node:

```
router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.render('product/list', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});
router.get('/products', function(req, res) {

    var size = parseInt(req.query.pageSize);

    if (req.query.pageNumber == 1) {
        var page = 0;
    } else {
        var page = parseInt(req.query.pageNumber) * req.query.pageSize - req.query.pageSize;
    }

    Product.count()
        .exec(function(err, numberProducts) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Can not download this list'
                })
            } else {
                Product.find().skip(page).limit(size)
                    .exec(function(err, products) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(404).json({
                                message: 'Can not download this list'
                            })
                        } else {
                            res.json({
                                "count": numberProducts,
                                "products": products
                            })

                        }
                    })
            }
        })
});
```

and url address when I'm in site with list products in first page:
http://localhost:3000/product/list

Comment: You don't need to use ng-if="$index < 10" you can use `| limitTo:quantity`

Comment: can You correct my script because it does not work for me??

Comment: If you want to change the page with ui-router, the entire approach is wrong..if you want to paginate with urls you don't need the ng-repeat at all! Anyway it's not quick...